# How to see Successful and Unsuccessful login events in Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: command-line, login

What are the commands for seeing Successful and Unsuccessful login events in Ubuntu 14.04.5?

I tried `aureport -au -i --success` and `aureport -au -i --failed` , but I don't know what the code 133, 129 etc. mean there?

[image: Result for <code>aureport -au -i --failed</code>]

Comment: Those look like attempt or event numbers as they are in order.  What about looking at entries in the `/var/log/auth.log` file?

Comment: i tried `/var/log/auth.log` . There are many kinds of information in that file. How to identify the required information there?

Comment: You can try `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -i failed` which will show the failed attempts and what IP they came from.  And I believe that you can use `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -i "session opened"` for successful attempts.

Comment: I would suggest "lightdm:auth" for failed sessions and "lightdm:session" for successful sessions. The failed logins don't actually use the word "failed" and using "session opened" for successful attempts will return all the cron sessions as well.

Comment: CORRECTION: Just use `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep lightdm:auth` to display both successes and failures. Also, I was mistaken about which message was which. Failed login attempts don't use "failed" but they do use "failure".

Comment: @AndrewShum Consider making your comment into an actual answer.

Comment: `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep lightdm:auth` returns nothing on my host.  I get better results with `failure` though.

Comment: By the way, `failed` does return failed login attempt like `Nov  2 13:57:31 terrance-ubuntu sshd[12685]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 97.82.62.143 port 54075 ssh2`

Comment: @Terrance It looks like that is for ssh; I was assuming jabi was not talking about those. The reason being that the screen shots (s)he posted indicate (s)he is using lightdm. But if jabi is interested in ssh logins, then yours would definitely be needed.

Comment: @AndrewShum Ah, I see now.  I am not worried about physical security on my hosts as they automatically log in.  There is no lightdm:auth on the hosts because of that reason.  Regardless, it is the point of looking in the file for anything out of the ordinary, and if OP does have ssh enabled, it would be good to know if someone or thing is trying to access the host as well.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

The application you are using is fine for checking those. `aureport` comes in the `auditd` package and is not installed by default.

The columns in the report as as follows:

```
date time acct host term exe success event
```

Showing on my system if I run it without the `--success` or `--failed` it will show all:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo aureport -au -i
[sudo] password for terrance:           

Authentication Report
============================================
# date time acct host term exe success event
============================================
1. 11/02/2017 16:37:45 terrance ? /dev/pts/2 /usr/bin/sudo yes 90
2. 11/02/2017 16:39:14 terrance ? /dev/pts/2 /usr/bin/sudo yes 243
```

The `success` column is what shows if my login was successful or not.  As we can see on this one, both attempts at logging in were successful (yes).  The number on the last part of each line is just the `event` number at which it happened.  These numbers can be ignored.  It is all the information before it that is important.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @MichaelBay, I am reposting this as an answer. See the comments on the original post for the full conversation.

I suggest a modification to the solution proposed by @Terrance. First, failed attempts don't use "failed"; they use "failure". Second, using "session opened" will return more than just user sessions.

If you use `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep lightdm:auth`, you will get both successful and failed attempts. This assumes you are not interested in ssh/tty logins. To get successful ones only, `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "lightdm:auth): r"`. For failed ones only, `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "lightdm:auth): a"`.